# Autofac: How to limit the lifetime of an IDisposable object without passing around the IoC container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, dispose, idisposable, autofac

I'm currently learning how to use Autofac, and I'm stuck with disposing `IDisposable` objects deterministically. Let me first present the situation before I'll state my problem.

### Starting position:

Let's say my object model is defined through the following interfaces:

```
interface IApple : IDisposable
{
    void Consume();
}

interface IHorse
{
    void Eat(IApple apple);   // is supposed to call apple.Consume()
}

interface IHorseKeeper
{
    void FeedHorse();   // is supposed to call horse.Eat(apple)
                        //   where 'horse' is injected into IHorseKeeper
                        //   and 'apple' is generated by IHorseKeeper on-the-fly
}
```

Further, I define a delegate that will be used as an `IApple` factory:

```
delegate IApple AppleFactory;
```

### Autofac configuration:

Now, I would register the above types as follows -- note that I'm omitting the code of both classes `Apple` and `Horse`, since they're trivial to implement:

```
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<Apple>().As<IApple>();
builder.RegisterType<Horse>().As<IHorse>();
builder.RegisterType<HorseKeeper>().As<IHorseKeeper>();
builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<AppleFactory>();
```

### My problem:

I don't quite know how to implement method `IHorseKeeper.Feed`. Here's what I currently have:

```
class HorseKeeper : IHorseKeeper
{
    private readonly IHorse horse;
    private readonly AppleFactory appleFactory;

    public HorseKeeper(IHorse horse, AppleFactory appleFactory)
    //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                         constructor injection
    {
        this.horse = horse;
        this.appleFactory = appleFactory;
    }

    public void FeedHorse()
    {
        using (var apple = appleFactory())
        {
            horse.Eat(apple);
        }  // <- Dispose() apple now (ASAP), as it's no longer needed!
    }
}
```

This is the kind of code I would like to have, as it's completely Autofac-agnostic. It could just as well work with another IoC container, as long as `AppleFactory` works as expected.

However, because Autofac handles the `AppleFactory` for me, it will keep track of all `IApple` objects it produces for me, and will therefore want to `Dispose` them itself at the end of the container's lifetime. Ie., the produced `apple` will be disposed twice.

I suppose registering `IApple` as `.ExternallyOwned()` is no viable solution, as there might be cases where it's easier to let Autofac handle the `IApple`s' lifetime.

[Deterministic disposal with Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) requires the creation of a nested container using `container.BeginLifetimeScope()`, however I don't want to use this inside `HorseKeeper.FeedHorse` because then `HorseKeeper` becomes dependent on Autofac, and I would like to keep my code IoC-agnostic.

### Question:

How do I implement `HorseKeeper.FeedHorse` in a IoC (Autofac)-agnostic way while ensuring that on-the-fly generated objects are disposed properly?

Comment: I can't say how you can approach this issue with Autofac specifically, but on a general note, having IApple derive from IDisposable is a **Leaky Abstraction**. You would be better off reconsidering your design.

Comment: @Mark Seemann, I'm curious to learn why `IApple` should not require implementation classes to implement `IDisposable` as well. A brief explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Why should it? Implementing IDisposable indicates to the run-time as well as other developers that the type in question holds references to unmanaged memory. In the case of interfaces, this is simply impossible, so it indicates that you are letting your knowledge of one or more concrete implementations leak through into the abstraction.

Comment: In addition, take a look at Nicholas Blumhardt's comments from Feb 4, 5:10 AM in this discussion: http://cca.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=82987 It sums it up pretty nicely.

Comment: All right, thank you. I'll keep this in mind in the future! (However, I would still disagree in that `IDisposable` is only to be used for freeing unmanaged resources. There are other valid reasons for implementing `IDisposable` IMO.)

Comment: For all who read these comments: I would recommend reading an article by @nblumhardt, [An Autofac lifetime primer](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/), that explains how `IDisposable` is problematic in "program to an interface" scenarios, and how the issue is resolved with DI containers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other answers here are insightful, but have a problem. In both cases, if Apple has other dependencies that need disposal, correct cleanup won't happen.

Autofac 2 provides a new feature to help here, called "owned instances". I noticed that your registration code is Autofac 1.4, so if you're unable to upgrade let me know (there are other, less transparent, ways to do this.)

Register Apple as usual (not externally owned):

```
builder.RegisterType<Apple>().As<IApple>();
```

Declare AppleFactory as:

```
public delegate Owned<IApple> AppleFactory();
```

In Autofac 2, you do not need to call RegisterGeneratedFactory() anymore - this is automatic.

Then, in HorseKeeper, feed the horse like this:

```
public void FeedHorse()
{
    using (var apple = appleFactory())
    {
        horse.Eat(apple.Value);
    }
}
```

(Note the .Value property to get the underlying IApple.

At the end of the using block the apple, plus all of its dependencies, will be cleaned up.

Any other components that use IApple directly (as dependencies) will get the usual behaviour.

Comment: +1 this is much like the experimental MEF `PartCreator` which returns a `PartLifetimeContext`. @stakx: "inheriting" `ExternalOwned` wouldn't work - when and by whom would the dependencies of the dependencies get disposed? `Apple` can't know about those.

Comment: Ah, yes, really like the simplicity of Owned<T>

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to modify the Apple registration with the `ExternallyOwned` modifier. This instructs Autofac to not track the object for disposal, but rather let someone external (your code) handle the disposal. But as you state, you will now have to make sure that all instances of Apple are disposed manually, since you will get no automatic help from Autofac.

```
builder.RegisterType<Apple>().As<IApple>().ExternallyOwned();
```

With this registration your Feed code will work as expected, though.

**Note**: on the discussion whether the interface should inherit `IDisposable` or not: IMO, when an interface inherits `IDisposable`, this is an indication to the "consuming" developer that the instance should be disposed at some point in time. In the case of IApple, since that interface is also IDisposable, the developer should make sure to dispose instances (and **must** also then be registered as ExternallyOwned). On the other hand, if the Apple class looked like this:

```
class Apple: IApple, IDisposable
{ }
```

consumers of the IApple is now fully unaware of the fact that instances is IDisposable. In this case we'll let the container handle disposal.

So my conclusion is that it is up to me as the developer of Apple and IApple to choose whether I'll require consumers to handle disposal or leave it up to a container.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and useful explanation, especially about how `ExternallyOwned` can work together nicely with `IDisposable` towards a consistent design. I'm still a little disappointed though that this seems to be an all-or-nothing situation, ie. that there seems to be no reasonable way to tell Autofac to manage disposal only for certain instances.

Comment: Not sure I understand clearly what you mean with "certain instances". LifetimeScope is a way of having more finegrained control over disposal in the container but I can see how this exposes the container to otherwise unaware classes. Otherwise I cannot see how Autofac possibly can know when instances should be disposed or not, without any input from external code.

Comment: With "certain instances", I basically meant what @wcoenen demonstrated in his answer -- namely, registering the same concrete type twice, but for different interfaces, where one is marked as `ExternallyOwned` and the other isn't. A class can then choose from these versions and thereby remain largely IoC-agnostic (I think).

Comment: Owned<T> is the clue to Autofac that you're looking for. ExternallyOwned only applies to Apple, so if Apple has dependencies that require disposal this option will unfortunately "leak".

Answer (score 2):

If you sometimes want to manage the lifetime of Apple instances yourself, and sometimes let the container handle it, then you can define two interfaces:

```
public IApple
{
   void Consume();
}

public IDisposableApple : IApple, IDisposable
{
}
```

And then register the class twice:

```
builder.RegisterType<Apple>().As<IApple>();
builder.RegisterType<Apple>().As<IDisosableApple>().ExternallyOwned();
```

You can then inject a DisposableAppleFactory into classes that need to create and dispose apples.

For classes which just need an apple with the same lifetime as the container, you inject IApple instead.

However, the fact that you need both may indicate that you are mixing [newables and injectables](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/10/to-new-or-not-to-new.html). Apple may simply be a "newable" object, i.e. one that doesn't need to be managed by the IoC container.

Comment: This works given the object model above, but unfortunately as with the other suggestion it will "leak" if Apple itself has any dependencies that also require disposal.