# Is SingleInstance() is thread safe in window application

Tags: c#, multithreading, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a windows application, where I am implementing Dependency injection by Autofac. I have a DBContext class which interacts to db for sql operation. I am using EntityFramework. I have scenario that i need to fetch entities separately with data from db based on some primary key from different tables. Then after some business logic again I need to update those entities in db. But here either all fetched db entities should be updated or none. so I am following unit of work pattern for that. But when fetching db entities from repository with using same dbContext instance, it lost other entities from dbContext. I was using AsImplementedInterfaces() (from autofac) to resolve my DbContext instance, which is not working in  my scenario. I changed it SingleInstance() then I am able to achieve my requirement. My doubt here,  Is SingleInstance() is thread safe for windows application or for above scenario kind of work?

```
builder.Register(c => new PortalDbContext(connectionString)).As<IPortalDbContext>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

TO

```
builder.Register(c => new PortalDbContext(connectionString)).As<IPortalDbContext>().SingleInstance();
```

I have three repository classes, and one business layer (BL), BL calls all repository class one by one to fetch data with same DBContext instance. Then finally it calls one method DBContext.SaveChanges() which should save all entities data in once or no data should be updated if any one failed. It is working with SingleInstance() scope. But not sure if SingleInstance is thread safe or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to autfac the **service** resolution are thread safe [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/concurrency.html#handling-concurrency):

> All container operations are safe for use between multiple threads.

The only thing to keep in mind is that resolution context objects are single-threaded so you need to  **avoid** component registration as:

```
builder.Register(c => new MyComponent(c)); //DON'T DO!
```

but as:

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
  IContext threadSpecificContext = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>(); // access real context.
  return new MyComponent(threadSpecificContext);
}
```

(see that the `threadSpecificContext` has been resolved, and the "`c`" context has not been used)

In your case you didn't make use of the "`c`" context at all, also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706602/6844481).

Comment: I found the statement "ContainerBuilder is not thread-safe and is designed to be used only on a single thread at the time the application starts up." on autofac documentation. So because of this line I was in confusion if containerBuilder is itself not thread safe, then resolving my components through this how it can be thread safe.

Comment: I see, its a bit confusing,  this is why i bolded the service resolution. There is no need in make the `ContainerBuilder` itself multithreaded, in most cases you only build it in the "main" thread.