# What does lifetime scope mean in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

When I configure a `DbContext` with Autofac as "lifetime scope", then in the scope of a request that means that it is disposed of at the end of a request.

But what happens when we get a `DbContext` from the container in the `Application_Start()` method of an MVC application?

We have a settings class that is set up as a singleton:

`builder.RegisterType<Settings>().As<ISettings>().SingleInstance();`

And in `Application_Start()` we get the settings from the container:

`var settings = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISettings>();`

The Settings class is dependent on a `DbContext` - and the `DbContext` is set up in lifetime scope

We know that this is a [captive dependency](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html), but do not think that is an issue, because the class uses the context once only.

My concern is whether the `DbContext` ever releases its resources.

In `Application_Start()` are we in the scope of a request or are we in the scope of the application?

And if we are in the scope of the application does "lifetime scope" mean that we don't dispose of the `DbContext` until the application stops?

Comment: How did you get the context ? could you share some code ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand question expanded with code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources will be released one the scope disposed in your case it is the application scope so resources will be released when the application stopped.

In such a case I would use `Func<Owned<DbContext>>`, something like that :

```
public class Settings
{
    Settings(Func<Owned<DbContext>> contextFactory)
    {
        this._contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
    private readonly Object _lock = new Object();
    private readonly Func<Owned<DbContext>> _contextFactory;

    private Boolean _isSettingsLoaded = true;
    private Int32 _settingsA;

    public Int32 SettingsA
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureSettingsLoaded();
            return _settingsA;
        }
    }


    private void EnsureSettingsLoaded()
    {
        if (!this._isSettingsLoaded)
        {
            lock (this._lock)
            {
                if (!this._isSettingsLoaded)
                {
                    using (Owned<DbContext> context = this._contextFactory())
                    {
                        // context.Value.DoSomething(); 
                    }
                    this._isSettingsLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that I could simply create an explicit scope inside `Application_Start()`: `using (var scope = resolver.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var settings = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISettings>();
}`...thoughts?

Comment: It may work but the captive dependency is still there and you may use the disposed component outside this scope without noticing it and create bugs in the future. `Func<Owned<X>>` is IMHO a better solution, no possible bugs if you change something in your `Settings` implementation.

Comment: That is true, but I think I will get resistance to introducing a dependency on  `Autofac` here. Usually we want our classes to know nothing about the IoC implementation, do we not?

Comment: I agree with you but unfortunately as far as I know there is no equivalent as `Owned` in the .net framework. `Owned` is only used to help disposing object where you don't know if it implements `IDisposable` or not. In your case, if you inject DbContext which is `IDisposable` you can forget about `Owned`. Another solution would be to have the `Owned` equivalent in your core framework. BTW I would prefer having dependency on * Autofac* than having the captive dependency.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438274/is-it-bad-design-to-reference-autofac-in-my-projects-just-for-ownedt